# Composition of Darboux functions

Tags: real-analysis

If $f$ and $g$ are two Darboux functions, is their composition also a Darboux function? I believe it is, but I can't prove it.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you believe it is and what you tried to prove it?

Answer (score 3):

Let $a<b$ and $f(g(a))<t<f(g(b))$.

$f$ is Darboux, so there is $g(a)<s<g(b)$ such that $f(s)=t$. (Assuming $g(a)<g(b)$, otherwise swap)

$g$ is Darboux, so there is $a<r<b$ such that $g(r)=s$.

But then we have $a<r<b$ and $f(g(r))=t$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** By definition, for a Darboux function the image of an interval is an interval.